# How to change space between columns in matrix

Tags: matrices, markdown, size, gap

Im trying to write 2 matrices in Jupyter Notebook Markdown but I can't figure out how to make the 2 matrices to have the same size. I don't know if I can change the whole size or reduce the space between columns to make it look better.

[image]

This is my code:

```
$$ G_x = \begin{bmatrix} -1 & -2 & -1 \\  0 & 0 & 0 \\ 1 & 2 & 1 \end{bmatrix}$$

$$ G_y\begin{bmatrix} -1 & 0 & 1 \\  -2 & 0 & 2 \\ -1 & 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix}$$
```

Comment: Not related: In LaTeX, you should use `\[` and `\]` and not `$$`. See [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/503/why-is-preferable-to)

Comment: @F.Pantigny Im showing this on Jupyter Notebook so i have to surround it with $$ to show mathematical expression. [Latex equations in Jupyter](https://jupyter-notebook.readthedocs.io/en/stable/examples/Notebook/Working%20With%20Markdown%20Cells.html#LaTeX-equations) _italic_

Comment: You are right... I have learned something.

Comment: Sadly it seems like none of the answers actually work for Jupyter Notebook Markdown, which only has limited LaTeX functionality, as the questions asks, and [doesn't support usepackage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21192606/can-i-add-latex-packages-to-mathjax)

Comment: @aarribas12, have you considered accepting an answer?

Answer (score 6):

The package `nicematrix` has a feature dedicated to that problem.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix}

\begin{document}

\begin{NiceMatrixBlock}[auto-columns-width]
First matrix
\[G_x = \begin{bNiceMatrix} -1 & -2 & -1 \\  0 & 0 & 0 \\ 1 & 2 & 1 \end{bNiceMatrix}\]
and second matrix
\[G_y = \begin{bNiceMatrix} -1 & 0 & 1 \\  -2 & 0 & 2 \\ -1 & 0 & 1 \end{bNiceMatrix}\]
\end{NiceMatrixBlock}

\end{document}
```

You need several compilations.

[image: Output of the above code]

Comment: Sadly this won't work in Jupyter Notebook Markdown (specified in the question) as [usepackage is not supported](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21192606/can-i-add-latex-packages-to-mathjax).

Answer (score 4):

A possibility with `blkarray`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{blkarray, bigstrut}

\begin{document}

\[ 
  \begin{blockarray}{@{}r*{3}{r}}
    \begin{block}{@{}c@{\enspace}[*{3}{r}]} 
    & -1 & -2 & -1 \bigstrut[t] \\
    G_x = {}& 0 & 0 & 0 \\
     & 1 & 2 & 1 \\
    \end{block}\\[-1ex]
    \begin{block}{@{}c@{\enspace}[*{3}{r}]}
    & -1 & 0 & 1 \bigstrut[t] \\
    G_y = {}& -2 & 0 & 2\\
     & -1 & 0 & 1 \\
    \end{block}
  \end{blockarray}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Sadly this won't work in Jupyter Notebook Markdown (specified in the question) as [usepackage is not supported](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21192606/can-i-add-latex-packages-to-mathjax).

Answer (score 4):

Here are two additional solutions:

- use `\phantom{-}` directives to insert a more space, and use a `bmatrix*` environment rather than a `bmatrix` environment

  - pro: easy to use
  - con: need to insert 1 `\phantom` directive for each columns whose width needs fine-tuning
- load the `siunitx` package and use its `S` column type in a a bespoke `array` environment

  - pro: no more fine-tuning required
  - con: for easy-and-straightforward application, column types must be fairly simple

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools} % for 'bmatrix*' environment

\usepackage{siunitx} % for 'S' column type
\usepackage{array}   % for '\newcolumntype' macro
\newcolumntype{T}{S[table-format=-1.0]}  % <-- bespoke version of 'S' column type

\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
G_0 &= 
\begin{bmatrix*}[r]
  -1 & -2 & -1 \\  0 & 0 & 0 \\ 1 & 2 & 1 
\end{bmatrix*} \\
G_1 &= 
\begin{bmatrix*}[r] % <-- note use of 'bmatrix*' env.
  -1 & \phantom{-}0 & \phantom{-}1 \\  -2 & 0 & 2 \\ -1 & 0 & 1 
\end{bmatrix*} \\
G_2 &=
\left[ \begin{array}{@{} TTT @{}} %      <-- use the 'T' column type for all columns
  -1 & 0 & 1 \\  -2 & 0 & 2 \\ -1 & 0 & 1 % <-- note: no fine-tuning needed
\end{array}\right]
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

Comment: This is the only answer that (partially) works -- adding \phantom directly to the bmatrix environment. bmatrix*, siunitx and array won't work as Jupyter Notebook Markdown [does not support usepackage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21192606/can-i-add-latex-packages-to-mathjax)

Answer (score 2):

With `tabularray`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{amsmath}
\NewDocumentEnvironment{mymatrix}{+b}{
    \begin{+bmatrix}[columns={1.3em, r, colsep=2pt}]
    #1
    \end{+bmatrix}
    }{}

\begin{document}
    \[
    G_x = 
    \begin{mymatrix}
        -1 & -2 & -1 \\  0 & 0 & 0 \\ 1 & 2 & 1 
    \end{mymatrix}
    \]
    \[
    G_y = 
    \begin{mymatrix} 
       -1 & 0 & 1 \\  -2 & 0 & 2 \\ -1 & 0 & 1 
    \end{mymatrix}
    \]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Sadly this won't work in Jupyter Notebook Markdown (specified in the question) as [usepackage is not supported](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21192606/can-i-add-latex-packages-to-mathjax).

Comment: @penelope To downvote who's trying to help you, it's not a good way to have the answer you need.

Comment: This is a beautiful solution! I went with `[columns={1.0em, c, colsep=2pt}]` to great effect and named it `bbmatrix`.

Comment: @PatrickT Thank you!